# R strtoi() returns NA when the string starts with zero

Tags: r, string

I am using the R function `strtoi()` to convert a `character` string into an integer. Is there a way to make this function work when there are some zeros at the beginning of the string?

Example:

```
name = "09"
digit = strtoi(name)
# or strtoi("09")
```

output:

```
[1] NA
```

Thanks

Comment: Not always the case `strtoi(c("0xff", "077", "123"))#
[1] 255  63 123`

Comment: According to `?strtoi` `The standard C rules for choosing the base are that octal constants (prefix 0 not followed by x or X) and hexadecimal constants (prefix 0x or 0X`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just explicitly list the base so R knows it's a decimal number (assuming you are expecting just the number 9)

```
strtoi("09", base=10L)
# [1] 9
```